# How to export a module's configuration?

Tags: 7, features, configuration

I've set up a module on one site and want to export it to another site. From researching, I understand you can use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) to do this. However there is no documentation detailing this.

Any suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many

[Drupalise Me Feature introduction](https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-drupal-features-module?p=1170)

[Phase 2 feature slides.](http://www.slideshare.net/Phase2Technology/features-15070655)

[Code Karate Feature Series Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHbOh9bf1dg&list=PL-Ve2ZZ1kZNTykHOLO0jzRADq8iZxvzkU)

[Acquia Video Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoMS8Z3Wp2o)

As far my experience features is not just about how to do it, but also how well you do it. Doing it in wrong way can make the development nightmare. Once you get acquinted with features, I would recommend you to look for features best practices. [Do's and Don'ts](http://slides.com/arpitrastogi/agenda#) for feature module.